# How to apply RLS on table using value from same table

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, row-level-security

I have a table like below and two users `Soni` and `Garve`. I want to show few orders only to users based on their role and using value in `string_to_match` column.

[image]

user `Soni` can see `order_id` like below, all `product_keys` of an `order_id` if `order_id` has even one `string_to_match`=pending rows/orders.

[image]

similarly role `Garve` can see all `product_keys` of an `order_id` if `order_id` has `string_to_match=waiting orders`.

[image]

Is it possible in Postgres?

Answer (score 0):

If everybody has a roleid and based on you can decide ,so

```
-- roleid  1 = access to 'pending'
-- roleid 2 = access to 'waiting'

declare roleid integer;
select * from 
yourordertable t1
where  exists ( select 1 from yourordertable t2 
                where t2.order_id = t1.order_id
                and case roleid 
                   when 1 then t2.string_to_match = 'pending'
                   when 2 then t2.string_to_match = 'waiting'                         
              ) 
and case roleid when 2 then t2.string_to_match <> 'pending'
```

not sure about last condition but based on your last output screenshot, it filters out 'pending' status for 'waiting' status .if It is not needed you can remove it.

Comment: we have to define policy and expression is like below 

`CREATE POLICY general_pol ON yourordertable 
    FOR SELECT
    TO  public
    USING (CASE WHEN CURRENT_USER = 'Soni '
            THEN expresion
          ELSE expression END);`